# Bootstrap modal is not working with Bootstrap carousel

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, carousel, bootstrap-modal

I have a bootstrap modal which opens upon clicking the link. But it just does not work with the bootstrap carousel on the page.
I have tried placing the carousel HTML above the modal HTML and vice versa but nothing helped :(

The modal looks like this-
[image]

But it should actually be like this-
[image]

```js
$('.carousel').carousel({
  interval: 4000,
  pause: "false"
});


var $item = $('.carousel .item');
var $wHeight = $(window).height();

$item.height($wHeight); 
$item.addClass('full-screen');

$('.carousel img').each(function() {
  var $src = $(this).attr('src');
  var $color = $(this).attr('data-color');
  $(this).parent().css({
    'background-image' : 'url(' + $src + ')',
    'background-color' : $color
  });
  $(this).remove();
});

$(window).on('resize', function (){
  $wHeight = $(window).height();
  $item.height($wHeight);
});
```

```css
html, body {
 margin:0; 
 padding:0;
 height:100%;
 }

    /*Navigation Bar*/
 .nav {
 margin:0px; 
 }


 .navbar{
 margin-bottom:0px;
 font-family: 'Droid Serif', serif;
 font-size:20px; 
    
 }
 .navbar-inverse .navbar-brand{
 font-size:20px;
 font-family: 'Droid Serif', serif;
 color: #fed136; 
 }
   
 
 
 /*Carousel*/
 
   .full-screen {
   background-size: cover;
   background-position: center;
   background-repeat: no-repeat;
   }


    div.form-group{
    position:absolute;
    top:40%;
    left:40%; /* change to whatever you want */
    right:auto; /* change to whatever you want */
    bottom:auto; /* change to whatever you want */
    }

    .carousel img {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    min-width: 100%;
    height: 500px;
    z-index: -1;
    }

    #footer{
 background-color:black; 
 color:white;
 font-size:15px;
 text-align:center;
 }
  
 
 /*Modal*/
 .modal-header, h4, .close {
 background-color: #5cb85c;
 color:white !important;
 text-align: center;
 font-size: 30px;
 }

 .modal-footer {
 background-color: #f9f9f9;
 }

 .modal-body{
     max-height:calc(100vh - 210px);
     overflow-y:auto;
    }
 
 #register .modal-dialog  {
 width:40%;
 
 }
```

```html
<! doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">

 
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" >

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" >

<!-- Custom CSS -->
<link href="main.css" rel="stylesheet" type='text/css'> 

 
</head>  
  
<body data-spy="scroll" data-target=".navbar" data-offset="50"> 

<!--Navigation-->  
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">

<div class="conatiner-fluid">
     <!--page scroll button for -->
   <div class="navbar-header" role="navigation">
     <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target= "#myNavbar ">
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>   
     </button>
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="main.html">Bookify</a>
   </div> <!--page scroll button-->
   
   <div>
   <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">

      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li ><a href="main.html">Home</a></li>
        <li ><a href="about.html">About</a></li> 
  <li ><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li> 
  <li ><a href="cancellation.html">Cancellation</a></li>
        <li ><a href="#sign in/sign up" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Sign in /Sign up</a></li>
      </ul>
   </div> <!--ul-li-->
  </div> <!--navbar collapse-->
  </div> <!--container-fluid-->
</nav>
<!--Navigation-->

 

<!--Caresoul-->

<div id="mycarousel" class="carousel slide carousel-fit" data-ride="carousel ">

  <!-- Indicators -->
  <ol class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-target="#mycarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
    <li data-target="#mycarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
    <li data-target="#mycarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>    
  </ol>

  
  <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
  <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
    <div class="item active">
      <img src="bus6.jpg" data-color="lightblue" alt="First Image">  
    </div>
 
  
    <div class="item">
      <img src="road2.jpg" data-color="firebrick" alt="Second Image">      
    </div>
 
  <div class="item">
      <img src="seat1.jpg" data-color="firebrick" alt="Second Image">      
    </div>
 
    <!-- more slides here -->
  </div>

   
 <div class="form-group"> <!--Form-->
      <label class="control-label requiredField" for="select">
       From
       <span class="asteriskField">
        *
       </span>
      </label>
      <select class="select form-control" id="select" name="select">
       <option value="Mumbai">
        Banglore
       </option>
       <option value="Pune">
        Delhi
       </option>
       <option value="Delhi">
         Indore
       </option>
       <option value="Banglore">
        Mumbai
       </option>
       <option value="Indore">
        Pune 
       </option>
      </select>     
     
  
  <label class="control-label requiredField" for="select">
       To
       <span class="asteriskField">
        *
       </span>
      </label>
      <select class="select form-control" id="select" name="select">
       <option value="Mumbai">
        Banglore
       </option>
       <option value="Pune">
        Delhi
       </option>
       <option value="Delhi">
         Indore
       </option>
       <option value="Banglore">
        Mumbai
       </option>
       <option value="Indore">
        Pune 
       </option>
      </select>     
     
   <label>Select Date*</label>
  <input type="date" class="form-control input-lg" name="start" placeholder="Check In"> 
       </br>
     <a href="search.html" class="btn btn-success btn-block" role="button">Search</a>
     </div>
   
  <!--Form-->
  
    
  <!-- Controls -->
  <a class="left carousel-control" href="#mycarousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
  </a>
  <a class="right carousel-control" href="#mycarousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
  </a>
</div>

<!--Caresoul-->


<!--Footer-->
<div id="footer">
  <div class="container">
 <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12"> </br>
    <ul class="list-inline">                         
    <li> <a href="main.html">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="about.html">About</a> </li>
    <li> <a href="contact.html">Contact</a> </li>
    <li ><a href="cancellation.html">Cancellation</a></li>
          <li ><a href="#sign in/sign up" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Sign in /Sign up</a></li>
    </ul>
         </div> </br></br></br></br>
        <div class="col-md-12"> Copyright © 2016 Bookify. All Rights Reserved</div>   
 </div>
  </div>
</div>
<!--Footer-->




 <!-- Modal -->
  
  <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">

      <!-- Modal content-->
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
          <h4 style="color:red;"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-lock"></span> Login</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          <form role="form">
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="email"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope"></span> Email</label>
              <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="Enter email" required>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="password"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open"></span> Password</label>
              <input type="password" class="form-control" id="password" placeholder="Enter password" required>
            </div>
            <div class="checkbox">
              <label><input type="checkbox" value="" checked>Remember me</label>
            </div>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default btn-success btn-block"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-off"></span> Login</button>
          </form>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default btn-default pull-left" data-dismiss="modal"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span> Cancel</button>
          <p>Not a member? <a data-dismiss="modal" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#register">Sign up</a></p> 
          <p>Forgot <a href="#">Password?</a></p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>  

<!---Modal1---->

<!---Modal2---->
<div class="modal fade" id="register" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">

      <!-- Modal content-->
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
          <h4 style="color:red;"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-lock"></span>Register</h4>
        </div>
       <div class="modal-body">
            <form role="form">
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="firstName"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span>Name</label>
              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="firstName" placeholder="Name" required>
            </div>
   <div class="form-group">
              <label for="email"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope"></span>Email</label>
              <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="Email" required>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="password"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open"></span> Password</label>
              <input type="password" class="form-control" id="password" placeholder="Password" required>
            </div>
   
   <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="phonenum"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-phone"></span>Phone Number (format: xxxx-xxxxxx)</label>
                    <input type="tel" pattern="^\d{4}-\d{6}$" class="form-control"  placeholder="Number"required>    
                </div>
    
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="birthDate"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>Date of Birth</label>
                    <input type="date" id="birthDate" class="form-control" required>
               </div>
      
      <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="control-label col-sm-3">Gender</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-6">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-sm-4">
                                <label class="radio-inline">
                                    <input type="radio" name="radio-choice"  required>Female
                                </label>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-sm-4">
                                <label class="radio-inline">
                                    <input type="radio"  name="radio-choice" required >Male
                                </label>
                            </div>
                            
                        </div>
                    </div>
     
     <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-sm-9 col-sm-offset-3">
                        <div class="checkbox">
                            <label>
                                <input type="checkbox" required>I accept <a href="#">terms</a>
                            </label>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div> <!--form-group -->
        
         
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default btn-success btn-block"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-off"></span> Register</button>
          </form>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default btn-default pull-left" data-dismiss="modal"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span> Cancel</button>
          
    <p>Already a member?<a data-dismiss="modal" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Sign in</a></p> 
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
 </div>  
<!---Modal2---->




<!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
 
     
<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" ></script>

 
 <!--Custome Jquery-->
<script src="main.js"></script>

 
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use id selector for the form on the slider in **html**

```
<div id="example-form" class="form-group">
```

And in **main.css** change `div.form-group` to `#example-form`

```
#example-form{
position:absolute;
top:40%;
left:40%; /* change to whatever you want */
right:auto; /* change to whatever you want */
bottom:auto; /* change to whatever you want */
}
```

So that the styling applied only on the form on the page and not the form in the modal.

Comment: No, it does not work on chrome Version 50.0.2661.87 m . I have edited the question to add images of modal to show how it looks and how it should look

Comment: although this makes the modal work but removing this form- group CSS collapses  the form on the page. It seems that form and modal are colliding.